# 2000's horror movie involving parasites that infect bodies and violently burst out after some time (I think they burst out of the stomach)

Tags: identify-this-movie

US film, either a TV movie or theatrical movie

Story Points

- Many of the tiny parasites infect some uncooked (but soon to be cooked) burger patties during a town celebration.
- A father, mother and child are exploring in the woods near the celebrations. The father then falls into a small pond and is taken to a hospital
- The father is visited by his wife and one of the protagonists. Suddenly, something happens to the father and a fully grown parasite, I think about the size of a medium-large sized dog, bursts out and attacks and kills the wife and a nurse.
- Another scene has a minor character take a shower after feeling extremely unwell. Like the above scene, a parasite then violently bursts out of him.
- By the climax of the movie, two of the protagonists (along with a bearded man) find where all the parasites have gathered and plan to blow up the site. An old sheriff also accompanies them afterwards (I think he tried to stop them until he saw the parasites and decided to help them).
- As they run to safety, the sheriff is attacked by one of the parasites, but I think the bearded man saves him. He then says a cliche'd line "I'm getting to old for this". But he is then killed anyway as they are close to safety.
- The site is blown up and the parasites are killed. The film ends with one of the protagonists visiting the second one in the same hospital where the father above has treated. When they all say in relief that its all over, the camera then zooms in on the second protagonists belly, suggesting that he/she might also be infested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Larva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larva_(film)) from 2005.

> The film taking place in Host, Missouri about a species of fluke-like parasites that have been mutated after ingesting enhanced cow feed. They infect animals (including humans) from the inside and grow at an enormous rate, bursting out of their hosts when they became adults. They go on a rampage, eating anything in their way until they were all killed in a massive explosion.

Pretty sure most of the stuff you mentioned is there (a father falling into a pond and later dying in the hospital after a parasite bursts out of him; the sheriff saying "I'm getting too old for this" before they blow them all up etc). Here's the trailer ***[Warning: Graphic Visuals]***:

Comment: @Jackson: Feel free to upvote as well as accept!